# carouselview not working in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

In my xamarin forms project there are two carousels in homepage image carousel working but testimonial carousel stopped working 2 days ago here is the code for testimonial xamarin forms project

.xaml file Code :

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
   <Label Text="Testimonials" FontSize="15" TextColor="#3a5370" FontFamily="OpenSansBold.ttf#OpenSansBold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
   <forms:CarouselView x:Name="TestimonialSlider">
      <forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="Center">
               <Label Text="{Binding testitext}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
               <Label Text="{Binding owner}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
      </forms:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
   </forms:CarouselView>
</StackLayout>
```

xaml.cs file code :

```
public class testicar
{
    public string testitext { get; set; }
    public string owner { get; set; }
}

List<testicar> testimonial;

public HomePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    testimonial = new List<testicar>();

    testimonial.Add(new testicar
    {
        testitext = "hi",
        owner = "how are you ?"
    });

    testimonial.Add(new testicar
    {
        testitext = "hi",
        owner = "how are you ?"
    });

    testimonial.Add(new testicar
    {
        testitext = "hi",
        owner = "how are you ?"
    });

    TestimonialSlider.ItemsSource = testimonial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be height issue. Your content overilap with image. just play with height and check. It should be work.